# Java TCP server with different kind of clients

Tags: java, tcp

I want to code a TCP server in java that has sockets for 2 different kind of users (one device client and one user client). How is this possible to connect the device client to a specific device socket and user client to the user socket in the server?

```
 ServerSocket serverSocket = null;
   int port = 1234;
    try {
        serverSocket = new ServerSocket(port);
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.println("TCP server created on port " + port);

    new DeviceServer(serverSocket).start();
    new UserServer(serverSocket).start();
```

Device Server creates a client socket with streams
and user server creats a client socket as well.

I want the user client to connect to the user socket only and device client to connect to the device socket only!

Comment: So you need two sockets and two ports.

Comment: so two server Sockets on two different ports

Comment: Or you can use the same port, if you can work out e.g. by protocol or source, which type of connection you have. Using two server socket ports is simpler.

Comment: @ΔημήτρηςΔημητρίου Yes, that's what 'two ports' means. NB The `accept()` calls should be inside the `try` block.